# Options in jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

does the timeout be enabled in the retry of the pipeline? I tried the code..when the timeout exceeded, the retry option was working but without timeout.

```
stage (‘Build’) {

        options {
        retry(2)
        timeout(time: 10, unit: 'MINUTES')
        
        }
        steps {
           //code
        }
        post {  
            success { 
             //code
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it appears there is a bug in Jenkins declarative pipelines. Here is a simple repro:

```
pipeline {
    agent none
    stages {
        stage('With timeout') {
            options {
                retry(2)
                timeout(time: 5, unit: 'SECONDS')
            }
            steps {
                sleep time: 10, unit: 'SECONDS'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It succeeds when it really shouldn't.

Comment: I don't exactly understand this workaround.. When tried this solution, It retries without the timeout..but, I want the retry to have the timeout.

Comment: This is not a workaround, this is a reproduction. A workaround would be to move the `timeout` option inside the `steps`.

Comment: Hi Thanks! but is there any way to have timeout inside options or do you know where to report this bug?

Comment: Already reported https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-71920 :)

Answer (score 0):

How about moving the timeout into the stages?

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            options {
                retry(2)
            }
            steps {
                timeout(time: 10, unit: 'MINUTES') {
                    sh 'your-command'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As I am automating the pipeline, I need timeout to be only inside options block